# Type error when using render when defining table columns in material table React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-table

HI I am using Material table to generate table view, here I defined the columns:

```
const columns: TableColumn[] = [
    {
        title: 'TYPE',
        field: 'type_of_action',
        highlight: true,
    },
    {
        title: 'DESCRIPTION',
        field: 'description',
    },
    {
        title: 'REFERENCE ID',
        field: 'reference_id'
    },
    {
        title: 'ENVIRONMENT',
        field: 'environment'
    },
    {
        title: 'SEVERITY',
        field: 'severity'
    },
    {
        title: 'PRIORITY',
        field: 'priority'
    },
    {
        title: 'ACTION',
        field: 'action',
        render: (rowData) => (
            console.log(rowData.priority). <---- error
        ),
    }
];
```

I used render in the last columns. but I saw a error in my Intellij like:

```
TS2339: Property 'priority' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

actually my code works and I can see **rowData.priority** printed out in my console.

I now rowData here is `type{}` and cannot recognize priority

In order to resolve this, I need to define it inside the `<MaterialTable>` tag, otherwise fields cannot be recognized?

But putting so many lines of codes in the tag looks very dirty.Any ways to **extract the column to a const variable** while avoiding the type error?

One idea in my mind is to pass the **columns variable** in first, and manipulate using `map`, but I am not sure how to do this?

Comment: Does `priority` is of type `number`?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `type` property to your columns definition when the type is different than `string`:

```js
const columns: TableColumn[] = [
{
        title: 'PRIORITY',
        field: 'priority',
        type: 'number'
    }
]
```

[Posible values](https://material-table.com/#/docs/all-props) are: `'boolean', 'numeric', 'date', 'datetime', 'time', 'currency'`.

You can find more details in this [PR](https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/issues/1523).

Comment: field prioprity is string type. even for all other fields, I get the error, not just `priority`

Comment: I know why, I need to define it inside the <MaterialTable> tag,  otherwise fields cannot be recognized? any other way to avoid it, putting so many lines of codes in the tag looks very dirty